# How to tell if Rails 3 transaction went through succesfully?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there a way to determine whether or not my transaction committed successfully (and did not rollback)?

```
Inventory.transaction do
  beads.each do |bead|
    # update something
    # insert something
    # delete something
  end
end
```

Or is something like this the only way?

```
success = false
Inventory.transaction do
  beads.each do |bead|
    # update something
    # insert something
    # delete something
  end
  success = true
end

if success
  # do something
end
```

Or, because the exception gets propagated, just assume successful if no exception?

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about exceptions, why not wrap it in a try/catch block (or `begin`/`rescue` block, to be more Rubyish)?

```
begin
  Inventory.transaction do
    beads.each do |bead|
      # update something
      # insert something
      # delete something
    end
  end
rescue WhateverError
  #handle error
end
```